# PS1 config in zsh causes previous line to be removed after each prompt redraw

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, zsh

My `.zsh` config has the following lines:

```
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    VIM_PROMPT="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/ [NORMAL]}/(main|viins)/}"
    PS1=$'\e[0;36m%n\e[m at \e[0;33m%m\e[m in \e[0;32m%~\e[m\e[0;34m$(vcs_info_wrapper)\e[m\e[1;33m$VIM_PROMPT\e[m\n$ '
    zle reset-prompt
}
```

What happens is that if the terminal window is too narrow, every time the prompt is redrawn the previous line is removed. For example, let's say I have the following prompt:

```
first line
some text here
another text here
sergiyb at wing in ~ [master *]
$
```

Then I press <kbd>Escape</kbd> and get

```
first line
some text here
sergiyb at wing in ~ [master *] [NORMAL]
$
```

Now if I press <kbd>i</kbd>, then I get this

```
first line
sergiyb at wing in ~ [master *]
$
```

Similarly, if I enter command `ls`, it lists all files, but removes last line:

```
sergiyb at wing in ~ [master *]
$ ls test_dir_with_files_1_to_10
file1   file2  file4  file6  file8
```

However, if the terminal window is wide enough, this does not happen, e.g.

```
sergiyb at wing in ~ [master *]
$ ls test_dir_with_files_1_to_10
file1  file10  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6  file7  file8  file9
```

Also if I try to make my PS1 line shorter, e.g. by removing user name, then it stops happening until I reduce width of the terminal even further.

Any idea what causes this and/or how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` can't accurately determine the size of the prompt because it doesn't know that the terminal does not display the ANSI escape codes as printable characters. Use `zsh`'s own formatting escapes instead.

```
PS1=$'%F{cyan}%n%f at %F{yellow}%m%f in %F{green}%~%F{blue}$(vcs_info_wrapper)%B%F{yellow}$VIM_PROMPT%f%b\n$ '
```

Comment: Can I get bright and dark yellow with these? In ANSI escape codes these would be `\e[0;33m` and `\e[1;33m`.

Comment: The `%B/%b` pair should be enabling bold/bright for the second yellow word.